# "yarn why" outputs multiple versions of the same package

Tags: node.js, npm

I have eslint 8.14.0 in my package.json. It works fine locally, but in CI for some reason Yarn installs version 7.32.0.

I ran `yarn why` to figure out what's going on and I'm confused about the output

```
yarn why v1.22.18
[1/4] Why do we have the module "eslint"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
[4/4] Calculating file sizes...
info 
=> Found "eslint@8.14.0"
info Has been hoisted to "eslint"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "workspace-aggregator-0efa6058-9ae7-4006-a032-0c0c9779b301" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#@wh-hc-dev#component-library#eslint"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#@wh-hc-dev#consumer-app#eslint"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#@wh-hc-dev#demo-app#eslint"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#@wh-hc-dev#eslint-plugin#eslint"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#@wh-hc-dev#old-mock-api#eslint"
info Disk size without dependencies: "4.56MB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "12.74MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "17.37MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 79
info 
=> Found "gatsby#eslint@7.32.0"
info This module exists because "_project_#@wh-hc-dev#demo-app#gatsby" depends on it.
Done in 2.34s.
```

What I'm trying to understand is what does it mean when `yarn why` says it found two versions, and how does it determine which one wins when I run `yarn eslint -v`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It's a monorepo. I was calling `yarn eslint` from the root. The fact that there was an `eslint` in `node_modules/.bin` at all was kind of a coincidence because ESLint was not installed in the root package.

I was able to fix it by installing ESLint in the root package:

```sh
yarn add -DW eslint
```

Which added the latest version to my package.json in the root.